# _registerComponent(…): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I have the problem :

> _registerComponent(…): Target container is not a DOM element.

This is the code :

The `homeMaster.Html` Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
         <title></title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\Content\bootstrap.min.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\PageStyle\MasterPageCss.css" />
         <script src="../Scripts/react/react.js"></script>
         <script src="../Scripts/react/react-dom.js"></script>
         <script src="../Scripts/react/browser.min.js"></script>
         <script src="../Scripts/react/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>
         <script async src="../Jsx/router.jsx"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div>
                 <app></app>
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

router.jsx Code :

```
"use strict";

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
        <ul className="header">
          <li><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink></li>
          <li><Link to="/stuff" activeClassName="active">Stuff</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/contact" activeClassName="active">Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <div className="content">{this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>HELLO</h2>
            <p>Cras facilisis urna ornare ex volutpat, et
        convallis erat elementum. Ut aliquam, ipsum vitae
        gravida suscipit, metus dui bibendum est, eget rhoncus nibh
        metus nec massa. Maecenas hendrerit laoreet augue
        nec molestie. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
        dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

        <p>Duis a turpis sed lacus dapibus elementum sed eu lectus.</p>
      </div>
        );
    }
});

var Contact = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>GOT QUESTIONS?</h2>
            <p>The easiest thing to do is post on
            our <a href="http://forum.kirupa.com">forums</a>.
            </p>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

var Stuff = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>STUFF</h2>
            <p>Mauris sem velit, vehicula eget sodales vitae,
            rhoncus eget sapien:</p>
            <ol>
              <li>Nulla pulvinar diam</li>
              <li>Facilisis bibendum</li>
              <li>Vestibulum vulputate</li>
              <li>Eget erat</li>
              <li>Id porttitor</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactRouter.Router>
    <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
      <ReactRouter.IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <ReactRouter.Route path="stuff" component={Stuff}>
      </ReactRouter.Route>
      <ReactRouter.Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
    </ReactRouter.Route>
  </ReactRouter.Router>,
  ReactRouter.destination);
```

The error is :

```
Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element. 
    at invariant (react.js:18350) 
    at Object._registerComponent (react.js:11043) 
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (react.js:11066) 
    at Object.wrapper [as _renderNewRootComponent] (react.js:12349) 
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (react.js:11146) 
    at Object.render (react.js:11166) 
    at Object.wrapper [as render] (react.js:12349) 
    at router.jsx [sm]:70  
    react.js:18357
```

The `homeMaster.html` doe's not recognizance the `router.jsx` file ,
Because it can't figure the target container `DOM_Element`.
I tried to put the `.jsx` file to compile before the html shows up.
And do async.

Comment: Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
    at invariant (react.js:18350)
    at Object._registerComponent (react.js:11043)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (react.js:11066)
    at Object.wrapper [as _renderNewRootComponent] (react.js:12349)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (react.js:11146)
    at Object.render (react.js:11166)
    at Object.wrapper [as render] (react.js:12349)
    at router.jsx [sm]:70

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue using jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

Your `render` call is attempting to use `ReactRouter.destination` as the DOM element to attach your application to. Unless you are setting that variable somewhere that isn't visible in the provided code, the issue is that that value is `undefined`, not a DOM element.

The second argument to `ReactDOM.render` should be a DOM element that exists in the page, i.e. given the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='app'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You would attach your application to the `#app` div by calling:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <ReactRouter.Router>
    ...
  </ReactRouter.Router>
), document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! its worked i tried to pull up the Points but i couldn't beacause no enough rep . Right now i understand how its work :)

Comment: You should be able to select this as the correct solution (the check mark)